# How to disable react native dev mode in debug build configuration for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to debug the application bootup and I want to skip the websocket server that downloads the js from the react native bundler.

Everything I've read on the internet just says to use release build configuration, but I need the debug configuration in order to debug my app.

I found this little bit in the documentation that prevents the bundle from re-building but it still connects to the websocket server to download the bundle instead of building it in.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#pro-tips

I also tried setting `#define RCT_DEV 0` in RTCDefines.h but that caused other build errors importing `RCTReconnectingWebsocket`...

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

This line tells application to load js from compiled bundle. If you don't have compiled bundle or didn't set to generate it automatically you can generate it with command:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Comment: I did that, but I still see the green bar at the top of my app when I launch it that connects to the dev server and downloads the bundle.

Comment: Press Cmd+Shift+K in XCode. It will clean the build folder and next time you build your app — it will be built from scratch.

Comment: And check that you don't have any other line defining `jsCodeLocation` in `AppDelegate.m`